Setup kaniko config.yml file
I am executing a Jenkins pipeline on a k8s based Jenkins server which has Kaniko pre-installed.
I would like to build a docker image of my application on this Jenkins server and push my image to another k8s based cluster. For this, I have my project structure as below.
.
└── My_Project/
    └── deployment/
        ├── .pipeline/
        │   └── config.yml
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── Jenkinsfile
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main.py
        └── dev_helm_values.yaml

My Jenkinsfile looks as below
@Library(['thor-helper','piper-lib','piper-lib-os'])

// Thor credentials stored in Jenkins.

stage("Build docker") {
    kanikoExecute script: this, buildOptions: ['--compressed-caching=false']
}

stage("Deploy to Thor") {
    steps {
        deployToThor(
            serviceName: "${service_name}",
            namespace: "mlh-${deployment_namespace}",
            imageName: image_name,
            imageTag: version,
            helmValuesFile: "${base_folder}/${helm_values_file}",
            basicAuthCredentials: env.service_user_credential_id,
            oauthPublicKey: env.service_oauth2_public_key,
            oauthCredentials: env.service_oauth2_credential_id,
            clientCertCredentials: env.service_client_cert_credential_id
        )
    }
}

My kanikoExecute config.yml file looks as below
steps:
  kanikoExecute:
    containerImage: "acrmlh.azurecr.io/develop/etr:0.0.1"
    dockerfilePath: "Dockerfile"
    containerRegistryUser: "acrmlh"
    containerRegistryUrl: "acrmlh.azurecr.io"
    containerRegistryPassword: "test"

and finally, when I run this on my k8s based Jenkins server, I get the following error
info  kanikoExecute - Error: error resolving dockerfile path: please provide a valid path to a Dockerfile

May I know how to find out the Docker file path here?

The documentation say you need to put the absolute path of the Docker file just like this /My_Project/deployment/Dockerfile.
Just like in the yaml example:

steps:

  - name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest

    args:

      [

        "--dockerfile=<path to Dockerfile within the build context>",

        "--context=dir://<path to build context>",

        "--destination=<gcr.io/$PROJECT/$IMAGE:$TAG>",

      ]


